# RDL report - change of header text in CSV export by parameter

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I am working on rdl reports and as I had to add multilingual support, I need to be able to change the column headers' text by the selected language parameter.
I added this very basic custom expression to the header:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Language.Value="EN", "Date", "DateInDifferentLanguage")
```

but when I export the report to CSV this is completely ignored, moreover, the column header will be the assigned value's name.
I tried to search for solution for almost 2 days, but the only thing I found that I should use the DataElementName property. Well, for static values it works, but as the text is parameter-dependent I have to use custom expressions and this property does not allow me to use anything like that.

Hopefully, there will be no difference in the solution for grouped columns.

So, my question is: is it possible to add parameter-dependent custom expressions to grouped/not grouped columns?

Comment: Do you mean to use either 'A' or 'B' expression, depending on the parameter?  Or simply to modify an expression based on the parameter?  These are both possible; I can elaborate if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The first one. Currently, we only have one language, but later we may have several others. The problem is not with the expression. The problem is that I cannot add expression to the DataElementName property. As far as I know, this is the only property that can change the column header in CSV export.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I just realized that you can't set the DataElementName property by expression.  I'll leave this up in the off-chance that it may help in some way.**

If you're wanting different expressions based on a parameter, try this:

Make sure you can see your Report Data.  **View -> Report Data(at the bottom)**

Start by creating the parameter.  Right click **Parameters** folder in the **Report Data window -> Add Parameter...**  Let's call it 'Language'.

In the available values tab, click Specify Values.  Add values for your languages, so the label will be what you want the viewer to see, make the value the same.

```
Label: English
Value: english
```

In the Expression you're trying to modify, simply put the available expressions you want in an `SWITCH()` block.

```
SWITCH(Parameters!Language.Value = 'english', [do english things],
       Parameters!Language.Value = 'spanish', [do spanish things],
       Parameters!Language.Value = 'chinese', [do chinese things],
       True, [do english things])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I do not have any problems with the parameters. I already have a language parameter that currently contains only English as selectable option.
My problem is that by selecting one of these parameters, how can I set the report column headers to be multilingual when exporting the report to CSV?

Comment: After looking into this, it appears that changing the DataElementName property dynamically is impossible.  I believe that is so that metadata remains consistent.  You may be able to some some interesting things by hosting the report on a website and conditionally modifying the HTML, but that's just a thought.  I'll leave this up in case it helps someone in some way.  Good luck!